# Looking for downloader web solution

Tags: solution

I'm looking for a web solution that will provide a web page/application that will let a user download our installer exe (all required files are contained in the exe) such that they can pause the download and resume it at any time.

It's a 1.4 GB file, and currently our only distribution model (we are on a 0 budget).

Any advice? Our end-users are expected to be very computer illiterate. Expected to be able to visit a webpage and follow a few steps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also need a hosting solution? For that part I don't know, but you could check out [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/). It supports resuming downloads, and it's open source - GNU General Public License.

Comment: No, I need a some kind of .exe that I can have the user download, that will manage a pauseable/resumable download from a specified location with 0 hassle to the end user. It has to be very user friendly

Comment: Have you tried my link? It basically is what you say that you need: an exe that manages pauseable/resumable downloads.